# Is there a way to get records by one condition

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to get records by only one condition instead of these three conditions :-

```
select * from product
where price != '' and price != 0 and price is not null
```

price column's DDL is `price varchar(15) default null`

Comment: Why are you storing `price` (which is presumably numeric...) in a `varchar`?

Comment: Actually I have storing prices like 10Rs,10usd etc.

Comment: You should reconsider that design decision...

Comment: Then you should have an additional currency-field, which will be varchar, or enum

Comment: @JochenJung Yes but its client's need... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the length of the condition, you could try this:

```
select * from product
where price > ''
```

or even probably better

```
select * from product
where price
```

Comment: It retrieves all records with no prices but in above example it retrieves all records having prices.  :)

Comment: @J.J. You must know the database to tell so :) - I think the first part is not what you asked for anyway. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, empty string evaluates as false, 0 evaluates as false and NULL evaluates as false, so this should work:

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE price;`

Comment: It will not working in if condition ? Like if(price,price,'N/a') as Price, I have no checked in where .. ?

Comment: It shoud work in if condition as well as anywhere else, but isn't the source of your problems the big P in Price? I imagine you are running a query like `SELECT *, IF(price, price, 'N/A') AS Price` and then you're trying to use `$result['price']`...

Comment: No, Some misuderstanding ,cypher  in if condition it will not working i checked now ? And its working in where clause, But i write it  price > ''  its working ...  ? As hakre says...

Comment: NOT WORKING, in if condition and where clause checked now again ? As hakre says that's right ? ?

Answer (score 0):

If you make price a numeric type and with NOT NULL for default, you can get away with checking just for != 0.